# format.html giving wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use the format.html thing but it is saying that I do not have enough arguments. It was working before on Rails 4.1 I believe. I just recently upgraded to 4.2.1 and now it will not work.

```
 if(!params[:search].blank?)
  @company = Company.where("comp_name LIKE ?", "#{params[:search]}%")
  @main_company = @company.first
  if(@main_company.nil?)
    flash.now[:danger] = "Invalid Company Name"
    @company = []
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do 
       results = @company.map do |company|
          { comp_name: company.comp_name }
        end
        render json: results
      end
      format.html{redirect_to company_path(@main_company)}
      # format.html { redirect_to company_path(@main_company) }
    end
  end
else
  @company = []
end
```

I receive the error:

```
wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
Extracted source (around line #18)          



  16 render json: results
  17 end
  18 format.html{redirect_to {company_path(@main_company)}}
  19 # format.html { redirect_to company_path(@main_company) }
  20 end
  21 end

  Rails.root: /Users/dariustran/Documents/rails_projects/ferch
  Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

  app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in home'
  app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:11:in `home'
```

Please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Following code should work for you.

```
#This should be in modal of company
def search_company_by_name params 
  if params[:search]
    l = Company.where("comp_name LIKE '%#{params[:search]}%'")
  else
    []
  end
end
# controller's action
res = Company.search_company_by_name params
respond_to do |format|
  format.json {render json: res}
end
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand the code, but I'll try to read through it and learn it as best as I can.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please accept answer if it works for you.

Comment: Hi Anand, I am receiving ActionController::UnknownFormat. I also updated the model function to be self.search_company_by_name. Thanks for the help!